# Error while compiling CODE

Tags: esp8266

Hey guys I have run my example with esp8266 2.4.2 version now I'm getting following error while compiling- C:\Users\Shree\Desktop\FirebaseDemo_ESP8266ex\FirebaseDemo_ESP8266ex.ino:21:29: fatal error: FirebaseArduino.h: No such file or directory #include  ^ compilation terminated. exit status 1 Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).

I'm trying to run FirebaseDemo_ESP8266 example but getting problem to compile that code. plzzz help me to solve this issue.

Comment: install the library

Comment: which libraries I need to install.?

Comment: FirebaseArduino.h?

Comment: It's strange that the missing library isn't mentioned in the error message, just an `^`. Or is it a copy and paste error?

Comment: **FirebaseArduino.h: No such file or directory** it is mentioned in your error message

Comment: Hey guys *Thank you* sooo so much to all of you for helping me. Finally after installing _FirebaseArduino_ library now I'm able to compile code without any error.